# Sixfab board not sending SMS

Tags: raspbian

I am using a SixFab IoT shield to send sms via my Pi and I am stuck with a stupid issue.

I am using one of their sample examples.

The code goes like this:

```py
'''
  sendSMS.py - This is basic SMS Service example.
  Created by Yasin Kaya (selengalp), October 31, 2018.
'''
from cellulariot import cellulariot
import time

node = cellulariot.CellularIoT()
node.disable()
time.sleep(0.5)
node.enable()
time.sleep(0.5)
node.powerUp()

node.getResponse("RDY")
node.sendATComm("ATE1","OK\r\n")

node.sendSMS("xxxxxxxxxxxxx","hello world!")
```

My terminal is not able to parse the AT command x1A and stuck at that point. MY board has network I did check it with the commands given. Anybody who had worked with this please help.

Comment: what does this mean? `not able to parse the AT command x1A` ..... if it an error, then  what is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: it keeps on printing x1A on terminal

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by sing this command node.setMode(GSM_ANY), what this does is, it gives the module independence to hop to different bands so that we are not stuck on the same one. The basic UDP example sets a fixed band of 900 which does not works in my case and causes the module to loose its network. Used lycamobile simcard

Comment: can you show the code of the working example?